# Program that switches between dual boot OS's?

Tags: dual-boot

Is there a program that gives me the option of switching between my dual boot OS's?

Something like a "Restart into " option add-on.  So instead of manually restarting my computer and selecting the OS in the grub boot screen, while already logged into an OS, I can just select "Restart into " and have it all done for me.

Yes I understand the need for something like this is just pure laziness.

Thanks

Comment: something like this? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43196/how-can-i-tell-grub-i-want-to-reboot-into-windows-before-i-reboot also: http://superuser.com/questions/285755/boot-to-windows-once-from-grub-then-back-to-ubuntu-on-next-boot

Answer (score 0):

The program that allows booting from more than one partition is the GRUB.  It is normally installed with Ubuntu, and you can search using GRUB as the search word.  IIRC, there is a standalone version somewhere, and that may be the solution to your question.

Comment: Not necessarily, sometimes this is controlled by the bios